# Blank objects in Qt Quick 2.0

Tags: qt5.1

I'm using Qt Creator 2.8.1 + Qt Quick 2.0.
Please, help me with the following: when i enter Qt Quick Designer for Qml file, i see blank objects, why?

[image: blank_objects]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be problem with OpenGl while running Ubuntu as guest system in VirtualBox.